# PHP e Javascript - Desabilitar um botão submit se textarea estiver vazio

Tags: javascript, textarea

No formulário do meu site, possuo um campo *textarea* e um botão *submit*. Segue o código dos dois:

```
<textarea name='texto1' id="txtBriefing" rows="5" style="font-family: Trebuchet MS; font-size: 16px; width: 394px; height: 100px" onkeyup="doSomething(this.value)" ></textarea>
<input name="btnEnvia" type="submit" value="Enviar" style="font-family: Trebuchet MS; font-size: 20px" />
```

Contudo, eu gostaria que esse botão só estivesse habilitado apenas se a *textarea* `txtBriefing` não estiver vazia. Já tentei alguns códigos em javascript com as funções `onkeyup` e `onchange` procurando na internet, mas nenhum funcionou até o momento.

O que pode ser feito pra esse caso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o evento `oninput` seja o ideal para este tipo de situação, digo isto pq ele é disparado apenas quando o valor do input é alterado.

Em todo caso, te aconselho a evitar setar eventos JS e styles no arquivo HTML.

```js
var txtBriefing = document.getElementById("txtBriefing");
var btnEnvia = document.getElementById("btnEnvia");

var onBriefingInput = function (event) {
  btnEnvia.disabled = !event.target.value;
}

txtBriefing.addEventListener("input", onBriefingInput);
txtBriefing.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

```css
#txtBriefing {
  font-family: Trebuchet MS; 
  font-size: 16px; 
  width: 394px; 
  height: 100px
}

#btnEnvia {
  font-family: Trebuchet MS; 
  font-size: 20px
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txtBriefing" name="texto1" rows="5"  ></textarea>
<input id="btnEnvia" name="btnEnvia" type="submit" value="Enviar" />
```

uma outra opção, é usar uma validação HTML5 `textarea[required]`, desta forma o formulário não será enviado se a textarea estiver vazia.

```css
#txtBriefing {
  font-family: Trebuchet MS; 
  font-size: 16px; 
  width: 394px; 
  height: 100px
}

#btnEnvia {
  font-family: Trebuchet MS; 
  font-size: 20px
}

/* O Estilo abaixo é valido apenas no FireFox. */
#form1:invalid #btnEnvia {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <textarea id="txtBriefing" name="texto1" rows="5" required ></textarea>
  <input id="btnEnvia" name="btnEnvia" type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Comment: não conhecia o evento `input`, faltou só explicar o motivo de chamar `dispatchEvent()`  `+1`

Comment: @Sanção, poderia ter usado um `onBriefingInput({ target: txtBriefing  })`, o `dispatchEvent` serve apenas para disparar o evento (no caso o `input`) associado o elemento. o equivalente no jQuery seria o `$("#txtBriefing").trigger("input")`

Answer (score 4):

**Com JavaScript**

Basta adicionar o ID no seu botão, e mudar o seu `onkeyup` do `textarea` para `onkeyup="javascript: doSomething(this)"`

```
function doSomething(input) {
    document.getElementById('btnEnvia').disabled = (input.value.length == 0);
}
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/5kdy8L63/2/

---

**Com jQuery**

```
$(function(){
   $('#txtBriefing').on('keyup', function(){
      $('#btnEnvia').prop('disabled', ($(this).val().length == 0)); 
   });
});
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/b9kzwjmt/

Comment: No primeiro exemplo, o botão está clicavel mesmo com a txtarea vazia.

Comment: Adiciona um `disabled="disabled"` direto no html, atualizei o exemplo

Comment: Editei a função para deixar ela mais limpa

Comment: Eu vi, +1 por ter dados opções diferentes e funcionais.

Comment: Valeu :), alguém deu -1 não sei o por qual motivo kkkkk